# Django - Alert user if exiting before submitting form

Tags: django, forms, exit

I have a page in my Django app with a form, and I would like to warn users if they try to exit the page without submitting the form.

Below is the answer that I found, but it also asks users if they want to leave when they are submitting the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = ''; });
    </script>
```

Below is my HTML code:

```
{% if list_of_students %}
    <form action="{% url 'attendance:submitAttendance' %}" method="post" name="fullForm">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name<br><br></th>
                <th>P/A/L<br><br></th>
                <th>Comment<br><span style="font-size: 12px;">Please note that comments for students marked<br>present will not be saved.</span></th>
            </tr>
            {% for student in list_of_students %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="student">{{student}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="radio-button">
                            {% for attendanceCategory in list_of_attendanceCategories %}
                            {% if attendanceCategory.attendancecategory == "Present" %}    
                                <input type="radio" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_attendancecategory' id='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceCategory}}' value={{attendanceCategory.attendancecategoryid}} checked="checked">
                                                                   
                                <label for='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceCategory}}' class='{{attendanceCategory}}'> {{attendanceCategory}}</label>
                            {% else %}
                                <input type="radio" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_attendancecategory' id='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceCategory}}' value={{attendanceCategory.attendancecategoryid}}>
                                <label for='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceCategory}}' class='{{attendanceCategory}}'> {{attendanceCategory}}</label>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <input type="text" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_comment' id="comment" maxlength="100">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Save Attendance"/>
      </form>
```

Comment: Why you wanna do it from backend ? When this can clearly be done on frontend and should be done on frontend.

Comment: I am not yet proficient in JavaScript, and I am running on a tight deadline. Is there a simple/easy to learn way to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: You can easy get the javascript code anywhere on the internet for this. Hint use javascript alert.